# Getting GCS path metadata for BigQuery external tables

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, external-tables

When querying Cloud Storage data using permanent external tables,

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE mydataset.sales
OPTIONS (
  format = 'CSV',
  uris = ['gs://mybucket/sales-google.csv', 'gs://mybucket/sales-microsoft.csv']
)
```

Is there a way to know which file the row was ingested from? Metadata?

```sql
SELECT * FROM mydataset.sales
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [_FIE_NAME](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage#the_file_name_pseudo_column) pseudo column:

```
SELECT 
  *,
  _FILE_NAME AS file_name
FROM mydataset.sales
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the _FILE_NAME pseudo column as outlined here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#the_file_name_pseudo_column